# Jmeter File upload - How to give path in jmeter to upload file

Tags: jmeter

Im trying to upload file and sending few parameters in the request but it looks it is not taking file path
-- payload

{"id":70,"student_id":24,"uploaded_by": "dbhadauria@concertai.com","document_name":"test","document_type":".png","files":
"CG.png"}

I m trying to give exact path also like C:/Files?CG.png but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you need to provide the file path and its [MIME type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types) under Files Upload tab of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler

[image]

If you're uncertain regarding how to properly build the file upload request you can just record it using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html), just make sure to copy the file(s) you will be uploading to "bin" folder of your JMeter installation, this way JMeter will be able to properly capture the request and generate the HTTP Request sampler.

More information: [Recording File Uploads with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-file-uploads-jmeter)